# Button not passing variable to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am new to ASP.net core and have run into an issue with passing a variable form a button to the controller. The examples that I have found seem to be straight forward and simple regarding this but I must be doing something wrong since I cannot get it to work. I am attempting to pass the variable in @Reload.Mail_Id to the method RecallRecord in the controller. If some one could tell me what I'm missing I would really appreciate it.

View

```
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Mail ID</th>
            <th>Process Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Brochure Order Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var Reload in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">@Reload.Mail_Id</td>
                <td class="text-center">@Reload.Created_Date</td>
                <td class="text-left">@Reload.Pax_Name_Envelope</td>
                <td class="text-right">@Reload.Address_1</td>
                <td class="text-right">@Reload.Brochure_Order_Name</td>
                <td>
                    <form asp-action="RecallRecord" method="post">
                        <input type="number" name="Mail_Id" value="@Reload.Mail_Id" />                            
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                            Recall
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Contoller

```
 public RedirectToActionResult RecallRecord(int MailID)
    {           
        {
            using (var ctx = new BrochureDbContext())
            {
                var reloadSet = ctx.Reload.FromSql($"usp_OAK_Brochure_Reload {MailID}")
                                          .ToList();
                return RedirectToAction("ReloadOrders");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your method as below

```
 public RedirectToActionResult RecallRecord(int Mail_Id)
    {           
        {
            using (var ctx = new BrochureDbContext())
            {
                var reloadSet = ctx.Reload.FromSql($"usp_OAK_Brochure_Reload {Mail_Id}")
                                          .ToList();
                return RedirectToAction("ReloadOrders");
            }
        }
    }
```